# AWS SNS SQS - Subscription filter policy for multiple logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

```
{
  "action": "Exception" / "Success"   ---> value will be either   "Exception" or "Success"
 
  "sourceClientName":  "A" / "B" / "C" / "D"   ---> One of the sourceClientName A or B or C Or D
}
```

I want to create a topic filter in such a way that, my SQS will get messages when

```
1> Any sourceClientName for "Exception" action
2> Any sourceClientName except "D" for Success action
```

I am new to aws sns topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the SNS subscription level.

Please follow the link. You can find your answer under the `Set filter policies to sns subscription` section:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/filter-messages-published-to-topics/